# Binary Search Tree - Java Implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I'm writing a program that utilizes a binary search tree to store data. In a previous program (unrelated), I was able to implement a linked list using an [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) provided with Java SE6. Is there something similar for a binary search tree, or will I need to "start from scratch"?

Comment: BST = Balanced Search Tree and not Binary Search Tree. Because not all binary trees are balanced.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree, BST is Binary Search Tree.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use a [`TreeMap data structure`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). `TreeMap` is implemented as a [red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which is a self-balancing binary search tree.

Answer (score 25):

According to [Collections Framework Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) you have two balanced tree implementations:

- [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
- [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: Note that a `TreeSet` is just a `TreeMap` without the values (so only keys). They're more or  less the same, internally. It depends on the implementation, of course, but most JRE's will have it implemented as: `public TreeSet() { this(new TreeMap<E,Object>()); }`

Answer (score 7):

Here is my simple binary search tree implementation in Java SE 1.8:

```
public class BSTNode
{
    int data;
    BSTNode parent;
    BSTNode left;
    BSTNode right;

    public BSTNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.parent = null;
    }

    public BSTNode()
    {
    }
}

public class BSTFunctions
{
    BSTNode ROOT;

    public BSTFunctions()
    {
        this.ROOT = null;
    }

    void insertNode(BSTNode node, int data)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new BSTNode(data);
            ROOT = node;
        }
        else if (data < node.data && node.left == null)
        {
            node.left = new BSTNode(data);
            node.left.parent = node;
        }
        else if (data >= node.data && node.right == null)
        {
            node.right = new BSTNode(data);
            node.right.parent = node;
        }
        else
        {
            if (data < node.data)
            {
                insertNode(node.left, data);
            }
            else
            {
                insertNode(node.right, data);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean search(BSTNode node, int data)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (node.data == data)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (data < node.data)
            {
                return search(node.left, data);
            }
            else
            {
                return search(node.right, data);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printInOrder(BSTNode node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            printInOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data + " - ");
            printInOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

    public void printPostOrder(BSTNode node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            printPostOrder(node.left);
            printPostOrder(node.right);
            System.out.print(node.data + " - ");
        }
    }

    public void printPreOrder(BSTNode node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            System.out.print(node.data + " - ");
            printPreOrder(node.left);
            printPreOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BSTFunctions f = new BSTFunctions();
        /**
         * Insert
         */
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 20);
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 5);
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 25);
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 3);
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 7);
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 27);
        f.insertNode(f.ROOT, 24);

        /**
         * Print
         */
        f.printInOrder(f.ROOT);
        System.out.println("");
        f.printPostOrder(f.ROOT);
        System.out.println("");
        f.printPreOrder(f.ROOT);
        System.out.println("");

        /**
         * Search
         */
        System.out.println(f.search(f.ROOT, 27) ? "Found" : "Not Found");
        System.out.println(f.search(f.ROOT, 10) ? "Found" : "Not Found");
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
3 - 5 - 7 - 20 - 24 - 25 - 27 - 
3 - 7 - 5 - 24 - 27 - 25 - 20 - 
20 - 5 - 3 - 7 - 25 - 24 - 27 - 
Found
Not Found
```

Comment: There is almost no point in having a binary search tree that does not balance itself

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyBSTree<K,V> implements MyTree<K,V>{
    private BSTNode<K,V> _root;
    private int _size;
    private Comparator<K> _comparator;
    private int mod = 0;

    public MyBSTree(Comparator<K> comparator){
        _comparator = comparator;
    }

    public Node<K,V> root(){
        return _root;
    }

    public int size(){
        return _size;
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key){
        if(_root == null){
            return false;
        }

        BSTNode<K,V> node = _root;

        while (node != null){
            int comparison = compare(key, node.key());

            if(comparison == 0){
                return true;
            }else if(comparison <= 0){
                node = node._left;
            }else {
                node = node._right;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int compare(K k1, K k2){
        if(_comparator != null){
            return _comparator.compare(k1,k2);
        }
        else {
            Comparable<K> comparable = (Comparable<K>)k1;
            return comparable.compareTo(k2);
        }
    }


    public V get(K key){
        Node<K,V> node = node(key);

        return node != null ? node.value() : null;
    }

    private BSTNode<K,V> node(K key){
        if(_root != null){
            BSTNode<K,V> node = _root;

            while (node != null){
                int comparison = compare(key, node.key());

                if(comparison == 0){
                    return node;
                }else if(comparison <= 0){
                    node = node._left;
                }else {
                    node = node._right;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void add(K key, V value){
        if(key == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("key");
        }

        if(_root == null){
            _root = new BSTNode<K, V>(key, value);
        }

        BSTNode<K,V> prev = null, curr = _root;
        boolean lastChildLeft = false;
        while(curr != null){
            int comparison = compare(key, curr.key());
            prev = curr;

            if(comparison == 0){
                curr._value = value;
                return;
            }else if(comparison < 0){
                curr = curr._left;
                lastChildLeft = true;
            }
            else{
                curr = curr._right;
                lastChildLeft = false;
            }
        }

        mod++;
        if(lastChildLeft){
            prev._left = new BSTNode<K, V>(key, value);
        }else {
            prev._right = new BSTNode<K, V>(key, value);
        }
    }

    private void removeNode(BSTNode<K,V> curr){
        if(curr.left() == null && curr.right() == null){
            if(curr == _root){
                _root = null;
            }else{
                if(curr.isLeft()) curr._parent._left = null;
                else curr._parent._right = null;
            }
        }
        else if(curr._left == null && curr._right != null){
            curr._key = curr._right._key;
            curr._value = curr._right._value;
            curr._left = curr._right._left;
            curr._right = curr._right._right;
        }
        else if(curr._left != null && curr._right == null){
            curr._key = curr._left._key;
            curr._value = curr._left._value;
            curr._right = curr._left._right;
            curr._left = curr._left._left;
        }
        else { // both left & right exist
            BSTNode<K,V> x = curr._left;
            // find right-most node of left sub-tree
            while (x._right != null){ 
                x = x._right;
            }
            // move that to current
            curr._key = x._key;
            curr._value = x._value;
            // delete duplicate data
            removeNode(x);
        }
    }


    public V remove(K key){
        BSTNode<K,V> curr = _root;
        V val = null;
        while(curr != null){
            int comparison = compare(key, curr.key());
            if(comparison == 0){
                val = curr._value;
                removeNode(curr);
                mod++;
                break;
            }else if(comparison < 0){
                curr = curr._left;
            }
            else{
                curr = curr._right;
            }
        }

        return val;
    }

    public Iterator<MyTree.Node<K,V>> iterator(){
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<Node<K,V>>{
        int _startMod;
        Stack<BSTNode<K,V>> _stack;

        public MyIterator(){
            _startMod = MyBSTree.this.mod;
            _stack = new Stack<BSTNode<K, V>>();

            BSTNode<K,V> node = MyBSTree.this._root;
            while (node != null){
                _stack.push(node);
                node = node._left;
            }
        }

        public void remove(){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public boolean hasNext(){
            if(MyBSTree.this.mod != _startMod){
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }

            return !_stack.empty();
        }

        public Node<K,V> next(){
            if(MyBSTree.this.mod != _startMod){
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }

            if(!hasNext()){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            BSTNode<K,V> node = _stack.pop();
            BSTNode<K,V> x = node._right;
            while (x != null){
                _stack.push(x);
                x = x._left;
            }

            return node;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(_root == null) return "[]";

        return _root.toString();
    }

    private static class BSTNode<K,V> implements Node<K,V>{
        K _key;
        V _value;
        BSTNode<K,V> _left, _right, _parent;

        public BSTNode(K key, V value){
            if(key == null){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("key");
            }

            _key = key;
            _value = value;
        }

        public K key(){
            return _key;
        }

        public V value(){
            return _value;
        }

        public Node<K,V> left(){
            return _left;
        }

        public Node<K,V> right(){
            return _right;
        }

        public Node<K,V> parent(){
            return _parent;
        }

        boolean isLeft(){
            if(_parent == null) return false;

            return _parent._left == this;
        }

        boolean isRight(){
            if(_parent == null) return false;

            return _parent._right == this;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            if(o == null){
                return false;
            }

            try{
                BSTNode<K,V> node = (BSTNode<K,V>)o;
                return node._key.equals(_key) && ((_value == null && node._value == null) || (_value != null && _value.equals(node._value)));
            }catch (ClassCastException ex){
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            int hashCode = _key.hashCode();

            if(_value != null){
                hashCode ^= _value.hashCode();
            }

            return hashCode;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            String leftStr = _left != null ? _left.toString() : "";
            String rightStr = _right != null ? _right.toString() : "";
            return "["+leftStr+" "+_key+" "+rightStr+"]";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This program has a functions for

1. Add Node
2. Display BST(Inorder)
3. Find Element
4. Find Successor

   ```
   class BNode{
       int data;
       BNode left, right;

       public BNode(int data){
           this.data = data;
           this.left = null;
           this.right = null;
       }
   }

   public class BST {
       static BNode root;

       public int add(int value){
           BNode newNode, current;

           newNode = new BNode(value);
           if(root == null){
               root = newNode;
               current = root;
           }
           else{
               current = root;
               while(current.left != null || current.right != null){
                   if(newNode.data < current.data){
                       if(current.left != null)
                           current = current.left;
                       else
                           break;
                   }                   
                   else{
                       if(current.right != null)
                           current = current.right;
                       else
                           break;
                   }                                           
               }
               if(newNode.data < current.data)
                   current.left = newNode;
               else
                   current.right = newNode;
           }

           return value;
       }

       public void inorder(BNode root){
           if (root != null) {
               inorder(root.left);
               System.out.println(root.data);
               inorder(root.right);
           }
       }

       public boolean find(int value){
           boolean flag = false;
           BNode current;
           current = root;
           while(current!= null){
               if(current.data == value){
                   flag = true;
                   break;
               }   
               else if(current.data > value)
                   current = current.left;
               else
                   current = current.right;
           }
           System.out.println("Is "+value+" present in tree? : "+flag);
           return flag;
       }

       public void successor(int value){
           BNode current;
           current = root;

           if(find(value)){
               while(current.data != value){
                   if(value < current.data && current.left != null){
                       System.out.println("Node is: "+current.data);
                       current = current.left;
                   }
                   else if(value > current.data && current.right != null){
                       System.out.println("Node is: "+current.data);
                       current = current.right;
                   }                   
               }
           }
           else
               System.out.println(value+" Element is not present in tree");
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           BST b = new BST();
           b.add(50);
           b.add(30);
           b.add(20);
           b.add(40);
           b.add(70);
           b.add(60);
           b.add(80);
           b.add(90);

           b.inorder(root);
           b.find(30);
           b.find(90);
           b.find(100);
           b.find(50);

           b.successor(90);
           System.out.println();
           b.successor(70);
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

---

***Here is the complete Implementation of Binary Search Tree In Java insert,search,countNodes,traversal,delete,empty,maximum & minimum node,find parent node,print all leaf node, get level,get height, get depth,print left view, mirror view***

---

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.experimental.max.MaxCore;

class BSTNode {

    BSTNode left = null;
    BSTNode rigth = null;
    int data = 0;

    public BSTNode() {
        super();
    }

    public BSTNode(int data) {
        this.left = null;
        this.rigth = null;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BSTNode [left=" + left + ", rigth=" + rigth + ", data=" + data + "]";
    }

}


class BinarySearchTree {

    BSTNode root = null;

    public BinarySearchTree() {

    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        BSTNode node = new BSTNode(data);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        BSTNode currentNode = root;
        BSTNode parentNode = null;

        while (true) {
            parentNode = currentNode;
            if (currentNode.data == data)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicates nodes note allowed in Binary Search Tree");

            if (currentNode.data > data) {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
                if (currentNode == null) {
                    parentNode.left = node;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.rigth;
                if (currentNode == null) {
                    parentNode.rigth = node;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int countNodes() {
        return countNodes(root);
    }

    private int countNodes(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int count = 1;
            count += countNodes(node.left);
            count += countNodes(node.rigth);
            return count;
        }
    }

    public boolean searchNode(int data) {
        if (empty())
            return empty();
        return searchNode(data, root);
    }

    public boolean searchNode(int data, BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.data == data)
                return true;
            else if (node.data > data)
                return searchNode(data, node.left);
            else if (node.data < data)
                return searchNode(data, node.rigth);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean delete(int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Tree is Empty");

        BSTNode currentNode = root;
        BSTNode parentNode = root;
        boolean isLeftChild = false;

        while (currentNode.data != data) {
            parentNode = currentNode;
            if (currentNode.data > data) {
                isLeftChild = true;
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            } else if (currentNode.data < data) {
                isLeftChild = false;
                currentNode = currentNode.rigth;
            }
            if (currentNode == null)
                return false;
        }

        // CASE 1: node with no child
        if (currentNode.left == null && currentNode.rigth == null) {
            if (currentNode == root)
                root = null;
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = null;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = null;
        }

        // CASE 2: if node with only one child
        else if (currentNode.left != null && currentNode.rigth == null) {
            if (root == currentNode) {
                root = currentNode.left;
            }
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = currentNode.left;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = currentNode.left;
        } else if (currentNode.rigth != null && currentNode.left == null) {
            if (root == currentNode)
                root = currentNode.rigth;
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = currentNode.rigth;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = currentNode.rigth;
        }

        // CASE 3: node with two child
        else if (currentNode.left != null && currentNode.rigth != null) {

            // Now we have to find minimum element in rigth sub tree
            // that is called successor
            BSTNode successor = getSuccessor(currentNode);
            if (currentNode == root)
                root = successor;
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = successor;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = successor;
            successor.left = currentNode.left;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private BSTNode getSuccessor(BSTNode deleteNode) {

        BSTNode successor = null;
        BSTNode parentSuccessor = null;
        BSTNode currentNode = deleteNode.left;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            parentSuccessor = successor;
            successor = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.left;
        }

        if (successor != deleteNode.rigth) {
            parentSuccessor.left = successor.left;
            successor.rigth = deleteNode.rigth;
        }

        return successor;
    }

    public int nodeWithMinimumValue() {
        return nodeWithMinimumValue(root);
    }

    private int nodeWithMinimumValue(BSTNode node) {
        if (node.left != null)
            return nodeWithMinimumValue(node.left);
        return node.data;
    }

    public int nodewithMaximumValue() {
        return nodewithMaximumValue(root);
    }

    private int nodewithMaximumValue(BSTNode node) {
        if (node.rigth != null)
            return nodewithMaximumValue(node.rigth);
        return node.data;
    }

    public int parent(int data) {
        return parent(root, data);
    }

    private int parent(BSTNode node, int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        if (root.data == data)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Parent node found");

        BSTNode parent = null;
        BSTNode current = node;

        while (current.data != data) {
            parent = current;
            if (current.data > data)
                current = current.left;
            else
                current = current.rigth;
            if (current == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(data + " is not a node in tree");
        }
        return parent.data;
    }

    public int sibling(int data) {
        return sibling(root, data);
    }

    private int sibling(BSTNode node, int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        if (root.data == data)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Parent node found");

        BSTNode cureent = node;
        BSTNode parent = null;
        boolean isLeft = false;

        while (cureent.data != data) {
            parent = cureent;
            if (cureent.data > data) {
                cureent = cureent.left;
                isLeft = true;
            } else {
                cureent = cureent.rigth;
                isLeft = false;
            }
            if (cureent == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Parent node found");
        }
        if (isLeft) {
            if (parent.rigth != null) {
                return parent.rigth.data;
            } else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Sibling is there");
        } else {
            if (parent.left != null)
                return parent.left.data;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Sibling is there");
        }
    }

    public void leafNodes() {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        leafNode(root);
    }

    private void leafNode(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        if (node.rigth == null && node.left == null)
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        leafNode(node.left);
        leafNode(node.rigth);
    }

    public int level(int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        return level(root, data, 1);
    }

    private int level(BSTNode node, int data, int level) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        if (node.data == data)
            return level;
        int result = level(node.left, data, level + 1);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        result = level(node.rigth, data, level + 1);
        return result;
    }

    public int depth() {
        return depth(root);
    }

    private int depth(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(depth(node.left), depth(node.rigth));
    }

    public int height() {
        return height(root);
    }

    private int height(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.rigth));
    }

    public void leftView() {
        leftView(root);
    }

    private void leftView(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        int height = height(node);

        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            printLeftView(node, i);
        }
    }

    private boolean printLeftView(BSTNode node, int level) {
        if (node == null)
            return false;

        if (level == 1) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            return true;
        } else {
            boolean left = printLeftView(node.left, level - 1);
            if (left)
                return true;
            else
                return printLeftView(node.rigth, level - 1);
        }
    }

    public void mirroeView() {
        BSTNode node = mirroeView(root);
        preorder(node);
        System.out.println();
        inorder(node);
        System.out.println();
        postorder(node);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private BSTNode mirroeView(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null || (node.left == null && node.rigth == null))
            return node;

        BSTNode temp = node.left;
        node.left = node.rigth;
        node.rigth = temp;

        mirroeView(node.left);
        mirroeView(node.rigth);
        return node;
    }

    public void preorder() {
        preorder(root);
    }

    private void preorder(BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            preorder(node.left);
            preorder(node.rigth);
        }
    }

    public void inorder() {
        inorder(root);
    }

    private void inorder(BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            inorder(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            inorder(node.rigth);
        }
    }

    public void postorder() {
        postorder(root);
    }

    private void postorder(BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            postorder(node.left);
            postorder(node.rigth);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        }
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return root == null;
    }

}

public class BinarySearchTreeTest {
    public static void main(String[] l) {
        System.out.println("Weleome to Binary Search Tree");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean yes = true;
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
        do {
            System.out.println("\n1. Insert");
            System.out.println("2. Search Node");
            System.out.println("3. Count Node");
            System.out.println("4. Empty Status");
            System.out.println("5. Delete Node");
            System.out.println("6. Node with Minimum Value");
            System.out.println("7. Node with Maximum Value");
            System.out.println("8. Find Parent node");
            System.out.println("9. Count no of links");
            System.out.println("10. Get the sibling of any node");
            System.out.println("11. Print all the leaf node");
            System.out.println("12. Get the level of node");
            System.out.println("13. Depth of the tree");
            System.out.println("14. Height of Binary Tree");
            System.out.println("15. Left View");
            System.out.println("16. Mirror Image of Binary Tree");
            System.out.println("Enter Your Choice :: ");
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter Value");
                    tree.insert(scanner.nextInt());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter the node");
                System.out.println(tree.searchNode(scanner.nextInt()));
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println(tree.countNodes());
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println(tree.empty());
                break;

            case 5:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println(tree.delete(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            case 6:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.nodeWithMinimumValue());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 7:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.nodewithMaximumValue());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 8:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println(tree.parent(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 9:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.countNodes() - 1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 10:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println(tree.sibling(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 11:
                try {
                    tree.leafNodes();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            case 12:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println("Level is : " + tree.level(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 13:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.depth());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 14:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.height());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 15:
                try {
                    tree.leftView();
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 16:
                try {
                    tree.mirroeView();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            tree.preorder();
            System.out.println();
            tree.inorder();
            System.out.println();
            tree.postorder();
        } while (yes);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: does your remove() method allow to remove root node?

Comment: @dimirsen yes you can remove any node whether its root or whatever.