# How to "delete" a node from a binary search tree in Java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I made a binary search tree in Java but I'm having troubles whit the deleting nodes part. I managed to erase the node when it has only 1 son, and I have the idea to make the deletion when it has 2 sons, anyways the method I'm using when it has no sons (when it's a leaf) is not working in Java. Normally in C++ I would assign the Node "null" but it doesn't work here.

```
if (numberOfSons(node) == 0) {
            node= null;
            return true;
}
```

That's the portion of the code that takes care of the nulling part. When I debug it, it is referencing the correct node and it's assigning it the null value, but when I return to the Frame where I'm calling the delete method for my tree the node is still there. What's the correct way to "null" an object in Java? I thought everything was a pointer in here and therefore this would work, but I think it doesn't.

Comment: Please take a look at existing [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373854/binary-search-tree-java-implementation?lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're `null`ing something you just make the reference in the scope you're in `null`. It doesn't affect anything outside.

Let me explain by example. Say you have a method foo:

```
public void foo(Node node) {
    node = null;
    if(node == null) {
      System.out.println("node is null");
    } else {
      System.out.println("node is not null");
    }
}
```

Now you call it like this:

```
public void doSomething() {
   Node node = new Node();
   foo(node);
    if(node == null) {
      System.out.println("Original node is null");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Original node is not null");
    }   
}
```

In your console you'll get:

```
node is null
original node in not null
```

The reason is that it's not a pointer, it's a reference. When you're `null`ing a reference, you just say "make this reference synonym to null". It doesn't mean that the object is deleted, it may still exist in other places. **There is no way to delete objects in java**. All you can do is make sure no other object points to them, and the garbage collector will delete the objects (sometime).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I wanted to know. Actually with your example I get"node is null
Original node is null", but I think it happens because of the "node = null" sentence before the second if. Is there a way I can erase from inside a method to any object that is pointing to that object?

Comment: @avatarbobo - I removed the `node = null` (it was a copy-paste mistake). There is no way you can delete for any object that is pointing to that object, that's not the way java works.

P.S - I'd appreciate if you upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing remains but to reinsert either left or right subtree. For instance:

```
class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        T value;
    }

    Node root;

    void delete(T soughtValue) {
        root = deleteRec(root, soughtValue);
    }

    Node deleteRec(Node node, T soughtValue) {
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int comparison = soughtValue.compareTo(node.value);
        if (comparison < 0) {
            node.left = deleteRec(node.left, soughtValue);
        } else if (comparison > 0) {
            node.right = deleteRec(node.right, soughtValue);
        } else {
            if (node.left == null) {
                return node.right;
            } else if (node.right == null) {
                return node.left;
            } else {
                // Two subtrees remain, do for instance:
                // Return left, with its greatest element getting
                // the right subtree.
                Node leftsRightmost = node.left;
                while (leftsRightmost.right != null) {
                    leftsRightmost = leftsRightmost.right;
                }
                leftsRightmost.right = node.right;
                return node.left;
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

As Java does not have aliases parameters as in C++ `Node*&` - a kind of in-out parameter, I use the result of `deleteRec` here. In java any function argument that is an object variable will never change the variable with another object instance. *That was one of the language design decisions like single inheritance.*