# How are nodes in binary search tree stored in java? and other questions related

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree. But I do not understand how they would be stored within an array. This is the data structure I am storing it in :

```
private Comparable[] intHeap;
```

I am still unsure on how to use comparable, please could someone explain the use of this data structure?

How would I inspect the largest and smallest elements of the binary search tree?

If I had the following tree, would it be stored in the intHeap as 1,3,4,6,7,8,10,13,14?

How do you know which node to go to next, if there is multiple node levels?

[image: binary search tree]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You obviously not the first person dealing with Java BSTs.  What have you already researched and found?

Comment: Regarding `Comparable`, if I search for "java comparable", the first hit is the Java doc page. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html  You should read it.  I'll admit it's a bit obtuse though, basically to compare two objects `x` and `y` you would call `x.compareTo(y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the declaration of an array, what you are building is a [*binary heap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) - a specialized tree-based data structure, which is typically stored in an array. Unlike tree structures that rely on explicit references, heaps rely on a clever indexing scheme that "packs" a tree into a linear data structure.

`Comparable` interface lets you build a heap that can store data of arbitrary classes, as long as they implement `Comparable` interface. This is useful, because you can build reusable code that works with numbers, strings, or objects of your own type.

> How do you know which node to go to next, if there is multiple node levels?

If a node is at the index `n`, its two children would be at indexes 2n + 1 and 2n + 2. If you are at index `k` and you want to follow the left subtree, set `k = 2*k+1`; if you want to follow the right subtree, set `k = 2*k+2`. Continue following the same algorithm until you hit a `null` element in your `intHeap` array.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation of the node index was really helpful and I love you x

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through a good tutorial.Just to give you heads up,the node will be like this

```
Class Node
{
   int data;//ideally should be generic.
   Node leftChild;
   Node rightChild;
   ...

}
```

Recommend you to visit [Binary Search Tree - Java Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373854/binary-search-tree-java-implementation)

Comment: Can you link me to a good tutorial please? It feels like days and I haven't gotten anywhere. Thank you.